# Case Statement Sql Multiple column check for dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a stored procdure that uses case statement as follows: What I am trying to do is evaluate 2 columns in the testTable for dates. So the below case statement says that if stop_date is null or greater than current date then set is_active cloumn is Y else N

What I am trying to do is also evaluate another date column say another_stop_date and check if it is null or has a date greater then today and use same logic to update the is_active column

I am not sure if we can use multiple case statement logic to update a single column?

I have commented the code below where I am not getting the right results

Basically need to evaluate stop_dt and another_stop_date columns from testTable!

```
USE [Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[p_test]
@Blank_Row CHAR(1) = 'N'

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TD  DATETIME

SELECT @TD = GETDATE()

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (

ID INT,
c_id   INT,
desc varchar(40),
date datetime,
s_col  TinyINT,
is_active char(1),
stuff VARCHAR(8))


 INSERT INTO @tempTable

 SELECT id, c_id, desc, max( date ), 1,

 CASE WHEN (stop_dt IS NULL OR stop_dt > @TD) THEN 'Y' 
 --//Case When (another_stop_date is NULL or another Stop_date > @TD) THEN 'Y'<-----confused here
 ELSE 'N' END,

 stuff

 FROM testTable

 GROUP BY id, stop_dt, c_id, desc, stuff, another_stop_date

 Select * from tempTable
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Should it only be 'Y' if both criteria are met? if so `case when (stop_dt is null or stop_dt > @td) and (another_stop_date is null or another_stop_date > @td) Then 'Y' Else 'N' End`

Comment: Thanks Laurence your solution was exactly what I needed, Thank you wish I could somehow mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine clauses in a case statement with the usual logical operators, as well as having separate cases:

```
Case 
    When 
        (stop_dt is null or stop_dt > @td) and
        (another_stop_date is null or another_stop_date > @td) 
    Then 'Y' 
    Else 'N' 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Case statement operate close to if statements and can have multiple clauses.

```
Case when condition_1 > 1 then 'hi'
when condition_1 < 14 then 'no'
when condition_89 > 12 then 'why is this here'
else 1
end
```

Apply it to your statement:

```
 CASE WHEN (stop_dt IS NULL OR stop_dt > @TD) THEN 'Y' 
 When (another_stop_date is NULL or another Stop_date > @TD) THEN 'Y'<-----confused here
 ELSE 'N' END
```